# Django-cms translatable objects

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-cms

I am implementing payment plans on an multilingual eshop based on django-cms. I need internationalized support for payment plans.

1. User can enter abritrary number of payment plans (implies standard django models)
2. Every payment plan must have a description in every language site supports (3 at the moment). Implies basic django-cms post or plugin.

Possible solutions I thought of, but did not fit..

1. If I go with django models, how do I handle i18n?
2. If I go with cms plugin, how would I link those descriptions to same django models in every language?
3. If I go with cms page, how do I create separate entities?

What is the most elegant solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Django-nani.

Comment: Don't use django-nani! Use the fork (django-hvad), since that's where the development continues!